# when we click on a button in tableview cell how to retrieve the text in the label of that particular cell

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone.I have a small doubt (i.e),I have create a table view in that i am placing all my book names and download option to that particular book in each cell like as below

```
Genesis    Download
Exodus     Download
Leviticus  Download
```

Here is the above Genesis,Exodus,Leviticus are booknames and download is the button for download that book like this i have 66 different books in table view.Here my question is when we click on download button i want to get the corresponding bookname of that tableview cell.
My code is like below

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 66;

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UIButton *downloadButton = nil;
//this is the custom cell i have created one class for this in that i am place the string titlelabel.
        CustomCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
             downloadButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            downloadButton.frame = CGRectMake(220,10,50,30);
            [downloadButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"download.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [downloadButton addTarget:self action:@selector(downloadButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            downloadButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            downloadButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            downloadButton.highlighted = YES;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:downloadButton];
      }    
        NSString *titleLabel = [[appDelegate getBookNames]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.TitleLabel.text = titleLabel;


        return cell;
    }

    -(void)downloadButtonClicked:(id)sender{

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the button action you can get the cell by accessing the superView

```
-(void)downloadButtonClicked:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    UIView *view = button.superview; //Cell contentView
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)view.superview;
    cell.textLabel.text; //Cell Text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
first set the tag of your label say it is 100.

//in the button click method...

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[button superview] superview];

UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];//this is for custom label 

NSLog(@"label text =%@",lbl.text);

else  NSLog(@"label text =%@",cell.titleLabel.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you tap on the table view cell the Delegate function will be called and it will give you the index path section and row value . When you putting button on table cells just allocate the tag - indexpath.row to the button tag. Find this tag when you call the button function and find the aray index to get the value for that index on the array.